# Why rails give us two methods to config rails cache_store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, configuration, memcached

I found there are two methods to `config cache_store`:

```
config.action_controller.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, "localhost"
```

[here is doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching.html)

and:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, "localhost"
```

It seems that they are same thing.

Why rails give us two methods to config cache store? Is there any thing different?

Answer (score 1):

Those values that you set in config.cache_store are used in config.action_controller.cache_store

The shorter version is simply easy to write out and remember.
See the rails source that demonstrates this at:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.7/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching.rb#L44